# How to hide padding on Bootstrap responsive mode?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, padding

Hey Stackoverlow family,
I'm facing a problem.I had padding-top 300 on 100% actual size but when I go to responsive mode it shows me same as original.I want to reduce padding.How can i do that?

Comment: Please show your code, and some screenshots of the element on desktop and mobile.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, we can't help much without seeing your code. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used the bootstrap library without making changes in tablet/mobile screen.

You need to understand how the responsive css works. 
In different window width: <768, between 768px - 960px, >960px
The website will refer to different groups of css code. If you only changed the padding on 100% actual size, it won't affect the responsive mode.

If you want to brutally affect the change to all screen size, just make a new custom css, point to your element and add `!important` at the end of the setting, like this:

```
#elementName{
    padding-top: 300px !important;
}
```

For more details, please refer to the bootstrap documentation
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I have a parent div width 800 height but I want my content after 300 padding. I give margin-top:300px; is working fine on normal width but when I move to small width like <768 it took gap 300px. Should I give it two CSS property one is for normal width another one is for small width is it possible? like on normal width margin-top:300px; and on small width margin-top:0px;.

Comment: wait, is it margin / padding ? They are different.

Comment: I use margin. But what is your suggestion to use margin or padding ?

Comment: Margin, just confused by your description (...want my content after 300 padding...) Of course you give 2 sets of css code for small (<768) and normal width(>768), please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp